# How do i append new data into an existing cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Assuming i have a 1x4 cell array, and i also have a `while loop` within which i call the function that produces a new result which is of the same size as my original array.

How do i append the new result into the existing one such that i still have a 1x4 array with the new results appended to the existing cells.

See an example code below:

```
% image
SegI = [2 2 2 0 0
        2 2 2 0 0
        1 1 2 0 0
        1 1 1 1 0
        1 1 1 1 1];

figure, imshow(SegI, [], 'InitialMagnification','fit')     
grid on; 

% face vectors obtained from each internal node in the image; such that %edge directions of 1|2 are denoted as 'm', and 0|2 as 'n', and others as NaN
% i made the 'b' up just for the purpose of detecting the output easily

allfaces = {NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN; NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN; 'm',NaN,'m',NaN; NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN; NaN,NaN,'n','n'; NaN,'n',NaN,'n'; NaN,'m',NaN,NaN; NaN,NaN,NaN,'m'; NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN; NaN,'m','b',NaN; 'm',NaN,NaN,'n';  NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN; NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN; NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN; NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN; NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN};


% find point vertices... which are nodes that contain pixel edges of both 1|2 and 0|2
Pvertex = find( any(strcmp('m', allfaces),2) & any(strcmp('n', allfaces),2) );


% create storage cell array as well as initialize Pvertex to inodej
myArray = cell(numel(Pvertex), 4);
inodej  = Pvertex;
cp = [3,3];     %coordinates of Pvertex


for k = 1: numel(Pvertex)

    % find next node from Pvertex
     [myArray, allfaces, inodej, ynode, xnode, dist_node] = Obtain_nodes(k, cp, inodej, myArray, allfaces);


    while dist_node < sqrt(2)
        % find nodes until exit loop
       [myArray, allfaces, inodej, ynode, xnode, dist_node] = Obtain_nodes(k, cp, inodej, myArray, allfaces);
    end


end
```

The function is given as:

```
function [myArray, allfaces, inodej, ynode, xnode, dist_node] = Obtain_nodes(k, cp, inodej, myArray, allfaces)
% This function computes new nodes from previous ones, as well as
% store each results in the storage cell "myArray" 


if ( find( strcmp('m', allfaces(inodej(k),:)) ) == 1 ) == true 
    % Find the node at the northern end of the face after inodej
    inodej(k,:) =  inodej(k,:) - 1;

    % extract the n, s, e, w faces from allfaces
    a = allfaces(inodej(k),:);

    % store the new results (exclude the existing result at the southern face)
    a(1) = {NaN};
    myArray(k,:) = a;

    % Obtain a new allfaces that deals the South face for the current node  
    allfaces(inodej(k),:) = a;


elseif ( find( strcmp('m', allfaces(inodej(k),:)) ) == 2 ) == true 
    % Find the node at the southern end of the face  after inodej
    inodej(k,:) = inodej(k,:) - 4;

    % extract n, s, e, w faces from allfaces
    a = allfaces(inodej(k),:);

    % store the new results (exclude the node at the northern face)
    a(2) = {NaN};
    myArray(k,:) = a;


    % Obtain a new allfaces that deals the North face for the current node
    allfaces(inodej(k),:) = a;

end


%# compute the distance between inodej and Pvertex
% firstly get the coordinates of the inodej
xnode(k) = mod(inodej(k,:) - 1, 4) + 1;
ynode(k) = (inodej(k,:) - xnode(k))/4 + 1;

% Then find the distance
dist_node(k,:) = sqrt( (cp(1) - ynode(k)).^2 + (cp(2) - xnode(k)).^2 );


end
```

See the figure below for some explanations.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQgSS.png)

The first function call in the `for loop` returns:

`inodej = 10`, and `myArray = {NaN, 'm', 'b', NaN}`

The function call within the `while loop` returns:

`inodej = 6`,  which draws a result from 6th row of `allfaces` to give:
`myArray = {NaN, NaN, NaN, 'n'}`

However, i do not get to see my initial (1st) result after the `while loop` exits because the new(2nd) result updates the cell array. Hence, the issue for me is how to get any new results stored and updated with the previous as the `while loop` is executed.

I would expect my final output to be something in this form:

```
[{NaN, NaN}] [{'m', NaN}] [{'b', NaN}] [{NaN, 'n'}]
```

Please, also bear in mind that I could for instance increase the search distance `(dist_node)` in which case i wouldn't know beforehand (except by visual inspection) how many new results i could get. Thus, the code will have to be able to append as many new results as obtainable.

Please, i need any help/suggestions/advice to get through this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you really need a cell array? A matrix would be faster and use less memory. Also, bear in mind that growing an array incurs some performance penalty. You will be better off if you can [preallocate](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html)

Comment: Thanks @Luis Mendo. I really don't know how to preallocate in this situation. Maybe you can help me out here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray1 = {NaN, 'm', 'b', NaN};
myArray2 = {NaN, NaN, NaN, 'n'};
result = cellfun(@(x,y) {x y}, myArray1, myArray2, 'UniformOutput', false)'
```

x: Each element of myArray1

y: Each element of myArray2

UniformOutput = false ensures the outputs are cells.

The prime in the end converts a row vector to column vector.

[Please read the cellfun documentation of MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

Comment: some explanation along with the solution would help others understand the problem.

Comment: Please guys take a look at the edited version. Thank you!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Kayess: the truth is i haven't posted the entire code because it will be too tiresome for anyone to look at. I have really tried to make this as simple and concise as possible by putting only the bits that are necessary for one to understand. I believe if you run the code and follow the little description below it, you'd most likely see what the issue is. Many thanks.